# How can I tell if a mithril item is a "perfect" mithril item?

Tags: lego-the-hobbit

The blacksmith's wife tells me that if I forge a mithril item "just right", it will become a "perfect version" of it. I assume this means not making any mistakes during the forging process. How can I tell if one of my items is perfectly forged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When at the Blacksmith's place, go to the spot where you can pick a new design to build, then navigate to an item that you have already forged. If it is perfect, it will say "Perfectly Forged".

[image: Mithril Shadow Blade, Perfectly Forged]

It turns out that all of my items were perfectly forged, and I'm not sure how you would make it not perfectly forged. So it's likely that all of your items are already that way.